# With an introduction by

Tags: copyright, collaboration, introduction

*This was originally a part of [my question about partnering with a website](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/45922/partnering-with-a-website), but I think it's separate enough to deserve its own post:*

Many books are published with an introduction by a better-known author, or academic, or public figure, whose name on the cover helps sell the book.  I assume in most cases all the arrangements are handled by the publisher.  But what if you want to or are able to arrange the introduction yourself?  Is the introducer a co-author?  Do they get a percentage of royalties?  Are they paid a flat fee?  Or do they typically do it out of the goodness of their hearts?

Comment: I would say that they are not a co-author, unless the introduction contains some major piece of scholarly work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a flat fee.  But I'm not certain, so I'll keep it in the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At my publishing company, we would ask well-known preachers to read our book then write something for the introduction or just a review for the back cover. I don't believe any of them were paid, but seeing as they were friends of my boss and ultimately not in it for the money, that would be why.

I would offer them a flat fee if they are someone you personally are able to contact. If it's someone who is well known—like JK Rowling for instance–they may end up wanting a small percentage.

Ultimately it differs per individual and you'll need to work it out with them.

Hope this helps some!